# SELECT, MAX? & COUNT on a unique column then GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've spent the past few days learning SQL from scratch. I'm currently trying to SELECT the records with the **highest** Revision values for every quote, then COUNT them and GROUP BY Account ID FROM tbl_quotes.

From:

```
 Account ID     Quote Number     Revision     QuoteID
 1              1/R0             0            1
 1              1/R1             1            2
 1              1/R2             2            3
 1              2/R0             0            4
 2              2/R0             0            4
 2              3/R0             0            5
 2              3/R1             1            6
```

Having absolutely no idea how group the quotes/revisions into 1,2 & 3. The closest I can get is:

```
SELECT AccountID, COUNT(QuoteNumber) AS [Num of Quotes]
FROM Filteredtbl_quotes
GROUP BY AccountID
```

Which returns:

```
Account ID     Num of Quotes
1              4
2              3
```

However I'm trying to achieve:

```
Account ID     Num of Quotes
1              2
2              2
```

How can I implement the MAX function (if most appropriate) to COUNT the highest Revision value for each quote 1, 2 & 3?

Comment: which is your expected result? first one or second one?

Comment: how about using ROW_NUMBER() and get the max of it.?

Comment: The second one. I'll look into Row_Numbers, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you explain how AccountID 2 has a count of 2? Only QuoteID 6 is in Revision 1?

Comment: At the moment it has a count of 3 (QuoteNumber 2/R0, 3/R0 & 3/R1). I'm trying to get AccountID to have a count of 2 by counting the latest revision of each quote associated with the account. But no idea how...

Comment: Do you have a separate column for QuoteNumber without the Revision? Seems that "1/R2" is quote number 1 with revision 2

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately no, it would have made things a little easier though.

Comment: You can extract the Quote from QuoteNumber, then use the result as subquery (just like another table)

Answer (score 0):

this would return the highest revision for each quote for each account

```
select accountID, quotenumber, max(revision) as revision 
From Filteredtbl_quotes
group by accountID, quotenumber
```

this would return how many different quotes each account has

```
select accountID, count(quotenumber)
from Filteredtbl_quotes
group by accountID
```

If either of those queries help you, not entirely sure whether you are after how many quotes each account has or max quote revisions or both but a combined result set would be a bit odd (would you be looking for 
`account 1 | 2 quotes | revision 2`
) as that doesn't tell you which of the two quotes is at revision 2

to combine the two you could do

```
select accountID, count(quotenumber)
from
 (select accountID, quotenumber, max(revision) as revision 
From Filteredtbl_quotes
group by accountID, quotenumber) as Active
group by accountID
```

but you'll find it has the same result as the second query i posted anyway

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm after a combination. The idea is the latest revision of a quote would be considered active, making the previous revisions redundant. Trying to count the total amount of 'Active' quotes has become difficult since there's no column representing this.

Comment: i've added a query that combines the two, however if every quote always has an active revision (inc revision 0) then you are doing extra processing for the same result. are there any quotes in the source table that don't have any active revisions?

Comment: or am i missing the point and a quote that only has revision 0 for an account inactive?

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accountID order by revision desc) as seqnum
      from Filteredtbl_quotes t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Actually, the key point is that this is not an aggregation query, because you want to select an entire row.  Another approach chooses the latest revision explicitly.  Here is one way with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from Filteredtbl_quotes t
where t.revision = (select max(t2.revision)
                    from Filteredtbl_quotes t2
                    where t.accountID = t2.accountID
                   );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, definitely helped. Apologies it's a little out of the original question's description but What kind of alterations would we need to the query if the AccountID was on another table with no overlapping columns? I could connect the tbl_accounts and tbl_quotes tables through a series on INNER JOINs, other than that i'm guessing its a CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @JustAnotherDowny . . . This answer is for the question that you asked.  If you have another question involving other tables, then ask *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Revision column for this calculation.

```
 SELECT AccountID,   SUM (CASE revision WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOtalRev
FROM Filteredtbl_quotes
GROUP BY AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the quote number from the revision 
Using `distinct`, extract (`substring` + `charindex`) inside a `subquery`.
You can now use this subquery just like another table (dataset).
i.e. aggregation (`count`/`sum`) can be implemented

```
    SELECT 
        SubQuery.AccountID AS [Account ID]
        , COUNT(SubQuery.QuoteNum) AS [Num of Quotes]
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                AccountID
                , SUBSTRING( QuoteNumber, 0, CHARINDEX('/', QuoteNumber, 1) ) AS QuoteNum
            FROM Filteredtbl_quotes
        ) SubQuery    
    GROUP BY 
        SubQuery.AccountID
```

Result:

```
Account ID    Num of Quotes
   1            2
   2            2
```

As for the Latest Revision per QuoteNumber, 
you can use another query:

```
    SELECT 
        SubQuery.QuoteNum
        , MAX(SubQuery.Revision) AS [Latest Revision]
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                 SUBSTRING( QuoteNumber, 0, CHARINDEX('/', QuoteNumber, 1) ) AS QuoteNum
                , Revision
            FROM Filteredtbl_quotes
        ) SubQuery    
    GROUP BY 
        SubQuery.QuoteNum
```

Result:

```
QuoteNum    Latest Revision
   1           2
   2           0
   3           1
```